# Using scipy.fsolve for a function with multiple inputs and one variable

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I'm trying to find the root of the function that takes 4 known entities (numpy arrays) and a scalar variable value. I'm trying the use the `scipy.fsolve` tool to find the root but I'm unable to use its syntax.

The function is -

```
def foo(T_,t_,x1_,x2_,y):

    P = np.zeros(len(t_), dtype=object)
 
    s = np.zeros(len(t_))
    
    for i in range(len(t_)):
        P[i] = model1.Pr(T_,t_[i],x1_[0][i],x2_[0][i])
        agg_disc_fact = sum(P[i]) * y * dt
        stub = 1
        final_term = P[i][-1] 
        s[i] = agg_disc_fact - stub + final_term
    
    return s[0]
```

The variable in the above function is `y`. The syntax I'm using to find the root is -

```
result = fsolve(func=foo, x0=0, args=(T,ts,x1,x2))
```

I'm also open to using other methods/tools of finding the root if they are more efficient or have more intuitive syntax.

Comment: The return value of `foo` is an array of numbers. When talking about root-finding, usually people are talking about a function which returns a scalar. In this context, what would the root be? Are you looking for the place where each element of the vector is zero?

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking for the first element of the return value array of foo to be zero. I have updated the function above.